# Copy files from one NTFS drive to another via a USB boot disk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, ntfs, file-transfer

I have 2 NTFS drives, and the one with my Windows 7 installation on it has died today.  The drive is definitely on the way out but, after using a USB boot disk, I was able to see that the data is intact.

My second NTFS drive also has data on it that I want to keep but, luckily, it's much larger than the bad drive, so I'd like to find a way to copy the bad drive to the good one.

The problem is this: I've been unable to find a USB boot disk (Rufus, UBCD, etc.), or utility, that supports NTFS read/write operations - the ones I've found (I don't remember the names as there were multiple utilities that came with the boot disks) only seem to support read operations.

Are there any free tools I can use that will allow me to copy all of the files from the first drive, to the second, without losing anything on either drive?

Comment: Windows PE boot disk would the best way to do this.  Ubuntu also supports NTFS out of the box and support is stable.

Comment: I'd put Hiren's BootCD in, and boot from MiniXP at the DOS screen.  This gives you a Windows environment which plays nice with NTFS.

Comment: @Ramhound Good shout with Ubuntu.  Windows PE seemed like a lot of work for the same thing.  I did go with the suggestion of Hiren's BootCD in the end, simply because I already had grub4DOS setup on my USB drive.  Thanks a lot, though.

Comment: @TKEyi60 I'm on MiniXP right now and, other than my drive crapping out every now and then, this worked perfectly.  As you were the first person to post that suggestion, if you'd like to make it an answer below, I'll accept it.  Cheers.

Comment: You said the Windows 7 drive is still available for now, so what about just booting into Windows 7’s System Recovery/Repair?

Comment: @Synetech The Windows 7 drive would only work as a slave.  I was unable to use it directly as the drive would constantly stop being read from and would eventually drop completely.  I had to keep restarting for the drive to be picked up again.  I have my stuff now though, so I just have to choose a drive.  Thanks for the comment all the same.

Comment: @JohnH, ah okay. Could you have configured your BIOS (or used a BIOS boot-time hotkey) to select the W7 drive as the boot device? Then you could have booted to the repair mode.

Comment: @Synetech Hi mate, unfortunately not.  The drive would fail to boot, would black screen during repair and would also fail halfway through CHKDSK.  Copying to the other drive was a last resort, and, sadly, also the only option I had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate that @John H!

I'd put Hiren's BootCD in, and boot from MiniXP at the DOS screen. This gives you a Windows environment which plays nice with NTFS.

I'm glad this worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Hiren's Boot CD`? You could make another bootable USB stick or a bootable CD-ROM. You could boot into `Mini Windows XP` using `Hiren's Boot CD` and use one of the provided Recovery applications (`DiskGenius` is what I use) to check if you can copy the contents from one drive to another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This has worked for me, although I'm using MiniXP and not DiskGenius.  However, if TKEyi60 posts his/her answer, I'll accept that instead as he/she posted first.  Thank you, all the same.

Comment: No worries, that is completely fair. He did comment first.